# LastModificationTime does not update when saving in Code Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I'm depending on a read-only property in outlook interop.

TaskItem.LastModificationTime

I apply a change and save the item. Unfortunately the last modification time does not update, while the values do save.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869323(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869323%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
        TaskItem ti = TaskUtil.GetTask(added.Id);            
        ti.Subject = changedname;            
        ti.Save();
```

How can I force this field to be updated (this very instant)?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model caches most MAPI values. Try to completely release the task (Marshal.ReleaseComObject) and reopen it using Namespace.GetItemFromID.

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObject on the item and then reopening it using Namespace.GetItemFromID does not apply new LastModificationTime (at least in Outlook 2010). Only releasing Outlook.NameSpace instance does this. However, closing/reopening the NameSpace object just for the sake of committing changes to an item seems like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut. Any better ideas?

Comment: More exactly, Save() does change LastModificationTime to the current time, Marshal.ReleaseComObject/Namespace.GetItemFromID immediately following it change nothing (as LastModificationTime is already updated) but then, when the app closes the session, the item somehow gets updated again, this time by Outlook itself.

Comment: Turns out that Exchange Cached Mode is a problem. If it's off, then the mentioned solution works. However, Outlook is extremely slow then so disabling this mode is not an option. The question remains..